# How to give priority to one table in Sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, union

I have two tables. In those tables, my stop id might be in one of them or both of them. If my stop id doesnt exist in B, it should pick from A. And if it doesnt exist in A, it should pick from B. And if stop id exist in both tables then I want to give priority to B and retrieve the row from B. Below query always returns the value from B. Can you help me out to fix this?

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " 
    + stop_id + "," 
    + name + ","
    + latitude + ","
    + longitude + ","

    +"1 as "+priority
    +" FROM "+ A

    +" UNION SELECT "
    + stop_id + "," 
    + name + ","
    + latitude + ","
    + longitude + ","
    +"2 as "+priority
    +" FROM "+ B
    +" WHERE " + stop_id + " =? "
    +" ORDER BY "+priority
    +" LIMIT 1 ";


    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {id});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UNION ALL` you should apply the `WHERE` clause to both `SELECT`s; your current code applies the condition to only the `B` side, while the `A` side returns all rows. `LIMIT 1` at the end hides this problem, though.

String concatenation does not make it easy to see, but you should be passing `id` twice, and using two `?` placeholders in your query:

```
SELECT stop_id, name, latitude, longitude, 1 as priority
FROM A
WHERE stop_id = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT stop_id, name, latitude, longitude, 2 as priority
FROM B
WHERE stop_id = ?
ORDER BY priority DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I just figured that out and came to tell this but thank you for your answer. =)